# Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}{f(x)dx}=0$ for non negative function such that the continuity point are zeros of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a non negative function such that if $c \in [0,1]$ is a continuity point of $f$ then $f(c)=0$. Prove that $\int_{0}^{1}{f(x)dx}=0$.

This problem it's about Riemann Integrals, I can't use Lebesgue Integral Theory.

This problem is the reciprocal of the case when $f\ge 0$ and $f$ then $f(c)=0$ (this implication is very simple).

I don't know what can I do in this problem. I tried the following:
Let suppose that $\int_{0}^{1}{f(x)dx} \ne 0$ then $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}{f(x)dx} \ne 0$ or $\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}{f(x)dx} \ne 0$ if the first then $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}}{f(x)dx} \ne 0$ or $\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}}{f(x)dx} \ne 0$ thus there exist a nested closed intervals sequence $I_J=[a_j,b_j]$ such that $I_{j+1} \subset I_j$ and $b_j-a_j \to 0$. Using the Nested Cantor Intervals Theorem  there exist $d\in I_j \forall j$ But I don't know if this is useful.

Note that $\forall \varepsilon >0$ the integral $\int_{d-\varepsilon}^{d+\varepsilon}{f(x)dx} \ne 0$.
Maybe $d$ is the point, but could be possible that $d$ is not a continuity point of $f$ so I'm not sure of what can I do.

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: I guess this is above my pay grade.  I'm wondering if someone can explain what is meant by continuity point (I couldn't find much through google).  I don't see how it's possible for $f(x) \geq 0$ (i.e. non-negative) and $\int f(x) = 0$ that $f(x)$ is anything but $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @Jared Consider $f(x)=1$ at $x=1/2$ and zero elsewhere.

Comment: I don't see how this is true, however. Consider the function that is $1/2$ if $x$ is rational and $1$ if $x$ is irrational. Since $f$ is nowhere continuous, every point of continuity of $f$ is a zero, but $f$ is obviously not Riemann integrable. I suppose you're additionally assuming that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: So $f(x)$ must either be $0$ or discontinuous, perhaps $f(x) = 1$ for rational $x$ and $f(x) = 0$ for irrational values?  Does the continuity point then mean these are points where $f(x)$ is continuous (in some $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of $x$)?  It seems to me then, that you can only integrate inside each of these regions, if $f(c) = 0$ at all of those points, then the only parts that contribute to the integral (the continuous parts) will all give $0$, right?  I'm guessing this is one of those obvious things that's hard to prove?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Wouldn't that function be continuous around the irrational numbers?  There aren't any rational numbers "adjacent" to any irrational number, but there are infinite number of irrational numbers (continuous) which fill the tiny holes between the rational numbers (even though those holes essentially have $0$ width--but that's a limit, right?).

Comment: @Jared No, we can always find a sequence of rational numbers $(r_n)$ that converge to an irrational number $\ell$, hence $\lim f(r_n)=\lim 1/2=1/2\neq 1=f(\ell)$.

Comment: This is related to the problem that if $f$ is integrable, then $\int_D |f| = 0$ if and only if $\{x \in D \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$ has measure zero.